# How to run a multilevel model with hurdle/zero-inflated and continuous dependent variable

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, model, negative-binomial-distribution, continuous-data

I have a dataset on voting loyalty (measured as percentage dissenting votes on votes cast) of parliamentarians (dependent variable, percentages) and the inclusiveness of their party's selection procedure (independent variable, continuous -could be transformed into categorical).

I have repeated measures of loyalty for each parliamentarian (all other variables are fixed), as I divide the legislature into 6month periods.

The idea is to test wether the candidate selection process (party level) influences the voting loyalty of a parliamentarian, and whether this changes over time (e.g. more influence right after or before elections, less so during the rest of the term).

Controls include variables on the individual level (seniority, gender,..) and party level (salience EU, ...).

A large portion of parliamentarians never casts a dissenting vote (100% loyalty - in the dataset transformed into 0% dissent). Because of this I would like to build a hurdle into the model, truncating at zero.

But, my variable is not a count variable. 
Also: the model must respect the multilevel nature of the data (multiple (time) observations per individual + individuals clustered in parties).

Is it possible to do a hurdle negative binominal if the data is continuous? 
Can anyone point me in the right direction to deal with this in R?

Just a thought:
I basically need the 0s truncated from the rest. Would it be an option to create an extra variable in my dataset that indicates whether or not the parliamentarian has cast at least one dissenting vote or not, and treat 0s in the original variable (percentage dissent) as missing data; then run separate models on 'what explains the zero's' and on 'what explains dissent among those who cast at least one dissenting vote', each dealing with a subset of the dataset? 
Or would I then be loosing information, not to say butcher the original data?

Answer (score 1):

Beta regression can be used to model continuous outcomes that are bounded between 0 and 1. This makes it a perfect candidate for modeling things like proportions and ratios.

If you want to include zeros, you can specify a hurdle model that looks at zero vs. above zero, and then looks at everything above zero—this is exactly what you describe in your question.

This can be done relatively painlessly using the `gamlss` package in R. The distribution you are looking for is the zero-inflated beta distribution, which is specified with the family argument being `BEINF0`.

Random effects can also be specified using that package. There are many good guides to `gamlss` on the internet; they have a website and book online that are helpful.

I developed a minor obsession with beta regression at one point and wrote a tutorial on using it, which is [at my GitHub.](https://github.com/markhwhiteii/beta_hurdle/blob/master/manuscript/beta_hurdle.pdf) I don’t address random effects, but you can do it with the `random` and `re` functions in `gamlss`.

Comment: That sounds like the solution I was looking for, I will try this and check out your tutorial, many thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to integrate the zero-and-one inflated (BEINF) gamlss (thank you Mark White) with a multilevel model (4 levels, of which lowest one repeated measures) with varying intercepts and fixed slopes? 

I need to ensure the multilevel nature of the data-set is properly taken into account, and I am not entirely confident on how to combine these two sorts of regression models. 

Is there any guidance / script on how to do this in R ?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!